Stretch title to fill a line without manual space adjustment
I'm looking for a command that can do something similar to a code below and that automatically decides on needed spacing
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Analysis \hfill of \hfill \textit{APOL1} \hfill mutation \hfill variants \hfill from \hfill sperm \hfill samples \hfill of \hfill African \hfill and \hfill European \hfill donors}

\end{document}


You may use the following:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

{
\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}
\setlength\spaceskip{.3333em plus 1fil}
\subsection{Analysis of \textit{APOL1} mutation variants from sperm samples of African and European donors}
}

\end{document}

The \parfillskip is added to the end of each paragraph (yes, the section title is a paragraph) and the \spaceskip is used between words. Setting \parfillskip to zero forces the last line of the paragraph to end up at the right border. This will only stretch the last line though. By also adding 1fil, i.e. infinite stretchable glue akin to your \hfill to each space, we get the stretching all over the section title.
Feel free to play with those values and have some fun!

You can set \parfillskip to 0, which means, that the last line has to be justified too:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\subsection[{Analysis of \textit{APOL1} mutation variants from sperm samples of African and European donors}]
{\parfillskip=0pt Analysis of \textit{APOL1} mutation variants from sperm samples of African and European donors}

\end{document}


But I do not recommend to use this, because it is very ugly, not good for readability and not good typography. Therefore I also do not show, how to use titlesec to add this as a default for all \subsection headings.
